# How to implement one-finger rotate GestureDetector in Android?

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I want to implement a GestureDetector which works with single finger touch.

If the finger is rotating clockwise it should increase a value otherwise it should decrease the value.

I don't want to use any handle.

Comment: OK, I'll be clearer.  Off topic, please read the FAQ.  If you edit to say what you have tried, what problems you have encountered and what exactly you want to achieve, I will reverse my close vote.  As it stands, you are effectively saying "give me some code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe that it is feasible to implement rotation gesture based on one finger. For some devices it is possible as they generate more than one `MotionEvent` when a single finger touches the screen therefore you may track the screen coordinates of each `MotionEvent` to find out the direction of the rotation. However, modern devices are optimized to generate a single `MotionEvent` for each finger touching the screen and while finger rotates through its own axes these devices do not generate any extra events.

**EDIT**
MotionEvent does not provide any ready method. It provides the screen coordinates for each event from the moment a finger touched the device's screen to the moment it is up. If you consider the screen as a coordinate system you may find the direction and angle of the rotation based on vectors formed between the start point and every other points generating during the rotation.

Comment: how can i find out direction of the rotation from the `MotionEvent`